# print_r for nodeList is not working

Tags: php

I have the following source code:

```
<?php

    function getTerms()
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML('https://charitablebookings.com/terms'); // loads your HTML
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        // returns a list of all links with rel=nofollow
        $nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='terms-conditions']");
        $temp_dom = new DOMDocument();
        $node = $nodeList->item(0);         
        $temp_dom = new DOMDocument();
        foreach($nodeList as $n) $temp_dom->appendChild($temp_dom->importNode($n,true));
        print_r($temp_dom->saveHTML());         

    }


    getTerms();
?>
```

which I'm trying to get a text from a web page by getting a specific class. I don't get anything on my browser when I try to print_r the temp_dom. And $node is null. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Probably shows that your XPath doesn't find anything, perhaps the content is loaded by Javascript.

Comment: @NigelRen when I try to `print_r($xpath);` I get this `DOMXPath Object ( [document] => (object value omitted) )`

Comment: Try printing out $nodeList instead, will show you how many matches there are.

Comment: @NigelRen I see, I got this `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that `DOMDocument`'s `loadHTML` method expects HTML content as its first parameter, not an URL.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = file_get_contents('https://charitablebookings.com/terms');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

And the second problem is with your XPath expression: `$xpath->query("//div[@class='terms-conditions']")` - as there is no `div` with `class` of `terms-conditions` in the document (it probably gets added by some JavaScript loader).

Comment: Thanks so much, I changed the first part. And I checked, yes there is no div with that class name. It is actually a section tag. I tried `$xpath->query("//section[@class='terms-conditions']")` but that didn't work. Any ideas ? Thanks again

Comment: As I pointed out in my reply - the page does not contain any element (not `div` nor `section`) with the class `terms-conditions` in the page source (use _View source_ function in Google Chrome - shortcut `Ctrl+U` to verify). The part which contains such class gets added later by JavaScript call (the website is built on Angular framework). Without interpreting the JavaScript calls, you cannot get to this "added" content in PHP. (You can also save the contents of `$html` variable to file to verify this.)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. adding `?_escaped_fragment_=` to the URL fixed the problem.